# Help needed to solve the integral $\int_0^\infty {\frac{{cy\exp({by}){\Gamma}\left[ {0,\frac{y}{b}} \right]}}{{1 + ay}}} dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

I am working with the following problem associated with the overall capacity of a Rayleigh fading channel:
\begin{equation}\int_0^\infty {\frac{{cy{e^{by}}{\Gamma}\left[ {0,\frac{y}{b}} \right]}}{{1 + ay}}} dy\end{equation}
I tried to find a closed form solution of the integral using different numerical approaches. I also tried to use Wolfram Mathematica 12.3. However, I couldn't come to a satisfying solution.

Then, I have tried to solve the integral manually using integration by parts assuming ${\frac{{cy{e^{by}}}}{{1 + ay}}}$ as $u$, and ${\Gamma}\left[ {0,\frac{y}{b}} \right]dy$ as $dv$; and found a closed form solution. I am not sure the approach is a correct way to solve an integral.

Could you please let me know your thoughts and help me to solve the integral? Thank you very much.

Comment: If you use IBP, you need to define $u$ and $dv$

Comment: I defined ${\frac{{cy{e^{by}}}}{{1 + ay}}}$ as $u$, and ${\Gamma}\left[ {0,\frac{y}{b}} \right]dy$ as $dv$.

Comment: Could you post the closed form you obtained (including the steps) ? Thanks

Comment: I realized the closed form solution I obtained is wrong. The integration of the Gamma function leads to another Gamma function, and the loop goes on.

Comment: I knew it. If you use $du={\frac{{c\,y\,{e^{by}}}}{{1 + ay}}}dy$ and $v={\Gamma}\left[ {0,\frac{y}{b}} \right]$, you get read of the gamma function but $\int u\,dv$ leads to nowhere.

Comment: The $\Gamma(0,w)$ is an [Ei function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gamma%280%2Cf%29). Would a geometric series on $\frac1{ay+1}$ work?